# Tensorflow cond behaves differently from source

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've built tensorflow from source. I am using tf.cond while loading data in order to select the image to load. It looks like this:

```
reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
_, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
features = tf.parse_single_example(
    serialized_example,
    features={
        'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32),
        'right': tf.VarLenFeature(tf.string),
        'center': tf.VarLenFeature(tf.string),
        'left': tf.VarLenFeature(tf.string)
    })
label = features['label']
image, label = tf.cond(rand < -0.7, lambda: (features['right'],label + 0.08), lambda: (features['center'], label))
image, label = tf.cond(rand > 0.7, lambda: (features['left'], label - 0.08), lambda: (image,label))
```

This works perfeclty fine with the version build from source (around 0.11rc1), however on other machines with 0.11rc2 (and rc1) installed with pip I get the following error:

```
File "./example_reader.py", line 29, in read_and_decode_single_example
    image, label = tf.cond(rand < -0.7, lambda: (features['right'],label + 0.08), lambda: (features['center'], label))
  File "./local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 1710, in cond
    orig_res, res_t = context_t.BuildCondBranch(fn1)
  File "./local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 1626, in BuildCondBranch
    elif v.name not in self._values:
AttributeError: 'SparseTensor' object has no attribute 'name'
```

I have no Idea what's the issue here... Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API for SparseTensor probably changed in between the two versions. Try the 1.0 version and see if the issue is still there.

Comment: yeah the build from source seemed to have newer api features. An update to 0.12 fixed. Don't know if I should switch to 1.0 anytime soon. Will it work flawlessly?

Comment: It should work flawlessly if you use the upgrade script provided in the 1.0 release to update your code.